# How to say somebody has a higher probability to catch a disease/get sick?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary

I'm looking for a phrase expressing somebody has a higher probability to catch a disease - either in a given time of year or due to his genetic predisposition.

My translator spit out that this type of person would be "more susceptible to diseases". Could I say it like that? What is the most natural way for an English speaker to say it?

Comment: You could look up synonyms for "prone". A typical phrase is "prone to disease". But "susceptible" seems okay too.

Comment: What makes you think that "more susceptible to disease[s]" might not be the "best" way to say it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers All examples I got from the internet were specified to some concrete disease or meant something completely different. But the anwer I think made it clear for me.

Comment: Probably: Even after taking note of your comment and the fact that you "accepted" @Peter's answer, I have no idea exactly what aspect of English you're asking about here (or more importantly, *how the answer enhanced your understanding*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wanted to know a phrase used to say "a person has a higher probability of acquiring a disease" and that's what I got with Peter's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of saying a person has a **higher probability** of acquiring a disease than the general population

> prone to
>   vulnerable to
>   predisposed to
>   susceptible to
>   at risk of
>   inclined to

The higher probability may be the result of **lifestyle** or **genetics**.